# Failed to save the context - foreign key issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have some problems during the SaveChangesAsync on my Context. I'm getting this error:
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

I think the reason of this error is self-explanatory, I have some violations in my entities regarding the external key. But...
Let me explain my environment:

1. I have 2 entities in a 1:N relationship (let's say 'Item1' can be associated with N 'Item2'). My entities look like:

   ```
   public class Item1
   {
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   [...]
   //navigation property
   public ICollection<Item2> Item2list{ get; set; }
   }

   public class Item2
   {
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   [..]
   //navigation property
   public int Item1Id{ get; set; }
   public Item1 Item1{ get; set; }

   }
   ```

So in my code, after I have built 2 instances of these items (oItem1 and oItem2), I have:

```
    oItem1.Item2list.Add(oItem2);

    myRepository.Add(oItem1);
```

And all seems fine but when I call the

```
Context.SaveChangesAsync()
```

I get (randomly, it doesn't appear every time) the error I have mentioned before. If I inspect the local cache of my context I see that some 'Item2' have an 'Item1Id = 0' that doesn't match the Id of the entity it should refer to.
And, it it appears, this error occurs just in 2-3 cases (over like 6000 entities and, every time, on different items). Of course I can't save them in my DB, but I don't get why this situation appear and how to fix it.

Note: I'm running in a multi-thread environment and the nature of my error suggests is something related it. But I would also point out that every threads build their own 'Item1' and 'Item2'. The repository (context) is the same for everyone, since I'm injecting it in the constructor of the main class.

I'm not expecting you to solve my problem (but if you do it would be great :P), but I just would like some hints/tips on what to check.

- Which parts would you look in?
- Have you experienced this kind of issue in the past?
- Could it be related to the fact I'm running with multi-thread?

I'm really stuck.

Comment: If the `DbContext` is shared between multiple threads, then this definitely is an issue. The entity instances are different, but the change tracker which maintains them and their state is one and the same, and isn't thread safe. In fact none of the EF context data structures is thread safe, hence using shared context is not recommended.

Comment: ok, I managed to change my code a bit as you suggested. Now every thread just return a list of Item1. So, I'm adding to the DbContext just after every task has returned and.... it works!!! Sometimes I just miss the easiest things :-( but it's not always easy to learn by myself... Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

`Item2` is referencing `Item1Id` of `Item1` as a foreign key which makes it essential that `Item1` should exist before its Id can exist in the `Item2` table.

You need to do the following in the given order:

- Save `Item1` to its corresponding table.
- Save `Item2` to its corresponding table. Set `Item1Id` to the `Id` of `Item1` from the above step.
- You can get list of `Item2` while fetching `Item1` enteries by simply including them. (See code below)

Code for writing to Database:

```
oItem1.Id = 2 //some Id
// setting other oItem1 properties

myRepository.Add(oItem1);

// setting oItem2 properties
oItem2.Item1Id = oItem1.Id;

myRepository.Add(oItem1);

Context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Code for reading from Database :

```
var items = dbContext.Item1.Include( i => i.Item2list).FirstOrDefault(); // I am fetching the first or default record from `Item1` along with the list of `Item2`s associated with it
```

Or use the equivalent method of your `Repository`